# How to change a Slider value from a different control event listener in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Say I have a `javafx.scene.control.Slider slider` and `javafx.scene.control.Button button`. What should I write in the button event handler to change the slider value programmatically on the button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setValue`  with value between min and max of your slider (0 and 1 by default) [http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setValue(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setValue%28double%29)

```
slider.setValue(0.5);
```

Comment: I have tried this already. Seems that my problem is not in doing it a wrong way but in a different thing. Thanks.